# How to draw "rotating" arrow as annotation?

Tags: swift, mapkit

Ok, my new task is this: inside a tracker app I have a map which I'm trying to annotate with custom heading arrow. I need this arrow to be rotated to a certain angle.

I have all the data (i.e. dergrees and locations) and this method:

```
headingImageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotationAngle))
```

So I tried:

1. Creating an annotation with

   ```
   let annotation = UserAnnotation(coordinate: locations.last!.coordinate)
   mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
   ```
2. Conforming to `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol

   ```
   extension TrackViewController: MKMapViewDelegate
   ```
3. Implementing methods like `:viewFor:` and also `:rendererFor:`

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

   if !overlay.isKind(of: MKPolyline.classForCoder()) {

       return MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)

   }

   let polyline = overlay as! MKPolyline
   let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
   renderer.strokeColor = .blue
   renderer.lineWidth = 3

   return renderer
   ```

   }

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is UserAnnotation {

           let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Online")
           annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "arrow")

           return annotationView

        }
   }
   ```

And so it kind of works, but I need to rotate an image every time location is updated. How should I do that? Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly is `headingImageView`? I don't see it used in your code samples anywhere. Is it the same view as `annotationView.image`?

Comment: Well, it's basically the same. I also tried to declare this arrow picture as global var but it looks so ugly. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

**you can use this code :**

but this is important to know you have to put (radian) for `rotationAngle`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

 if annotation is UserAnnotation {

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Online")
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "arrow")
    annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(//what you want with type of radian))
    return annotationView
 }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to be more helpful to those who come later to find this, you should click on edit and add an explanation/summary of how this code addresses the issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for now I did that:

1. Globally declared image of an arrow and an optional annotation

   ```
   let arrow = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow")
   var rotatedArrow: UIImage?
   var oldAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation?
   ```
2. Rotated image to a certain angle when I get this angle

   ```
   rotatedArrow = arrow.imageRotated(by: CGFloat(locations.last!.course))
   ```
3. Passed this rotated image to the delegate's method as

   ```
   annotationView.image = rotatedArrow

   return annotationView
   ```
4. Stored and deleted previous annotation

But it all looks soooo ugly

Comment: Sorry it's hard to completely grasp it without seeing the full source. Another thing you can do for performance is dequeue your annotation views from the mapview itself using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452672-dequeuereusableannotationview